# CACULATE MIN, MEDIAN, MAX AT ONCE

Tags: sql, max, min, median

Please help me to calculate the MIN, MEDIAN and MAX scores of the students from the result table AT ONCE. Result table: id, student_id,score

I found the way to get the median with the following code, but it returns median value only. How could I add min and max? Thank you so much

```
SELECT AVG(SCORE)::INT AS MEDIAN
FROM

(SELECT *, 
row_number() over(order by score desc) as desc_sc,
row_number() over(order by score asc) as asc_sc
FROM result
) as a

WHERE asc_sc IN (desc_sc,desc_sc+1,desc_sc-1)
```

Comment: Please help us with more info. What is your database ?

Comment: Hi @VBoka, thank you for asking. actually I gave you "Result table: id, student_id,score".  Also, I'm quite new so  hope you can tell me what else you need.

Comment: Hi @HoangNhi I am sorry but I do not understand your answer. I asked your database. Also, we need to see data you expect to get with your query and that is not this: "Result table: id, student_id,score". We want to see what data you expect to get after you execute your query. The Result table is your source table. There are some data in that table ? Show us few rows from that table and result you expect to get from that data. Also, one more time, what database do you use: Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL.... Let us know...

Comment: Hi @HoangNhi any feedback would be nice. You have two answers, are they ok ? Yes, great, accept them if you want to... If not then comment why not... Cheers!

Comment: My appologies for late reply. the 1st answer helped me to fix my wrong code and Im also thankful for the idea of percentile in the 2nd answer. Thank you for your comment, I would definitely give a clearer question with sample input and expected output next time. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT AVG(SCORE)::INT AS MEDIAN, min_score, max_score
FROM

(SELECT *, 
MIN(score) over (ORDER BY score ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as min_score,
MAX(score) over (ORDER BY score ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as max_score,
row_number() over(order by score desc) as desc_sc,
row_number() over(order by score asc) as asc_sc
FROM result
) as a

WHERE asc_sc IN (desc_sc,desc_sc+1,desc_sc-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use syntax like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        MIN(score) OVER () as min_score,
        MAX(score) OVER () as max_score,
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SCORE) OVER () as median 
FROM result;
```

Some databases support a `median()` function.  In those databases, you could just use:

```
SELECT MIN(score) as min_score, MAX(score) as max_score,
       MEDIAN(score) as median_score
FROM result;
```